# C# Return Zero in Corresponding Input Type

Tags: c#, dynamic

I want a function that does this:

```
    private static dynamic Zero(Type T)
    {
        if (T == typeof(Decimal))
        {
            return Decimal.Zero;
        }
        else if (T == typeof(Double))
        {
            return new Double();
        }
        else if (T == typeof(Int64))
        {
            return new Int64();
        }
        ...
    }
```

But for all Types.  I'd like to avoid writing a giant else if statement.  Is there any other way to do this?  I'm using C# 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a value type, the default constructor would work.

```
if(T.IsValueType()) return Activator.CreateInstance(T);
```

Then you can do other stuff, like testing for a Zero method on the type and if so, calling that.

Comment: ...and presumably an `else return null;` to handle the "zero" case for reference types.  One possible special case may be strings depending on whether the original poster wants a "zero string" to be null or empty (assuming he cares about strings at all!).

Comment: Thank you kindly.  I messed around with the reflection stuff earlier, and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I don't even need to check for IsValueType because I do the check before I call the Zero() function.  Thanks again.

Comment: solutions like this always seem to me to be a heavy-handed use of reflection. But I guess that's all default(T) would do anyway. sigh!...

Answer (score 5):

```
return default(T);
```

Comment: Doesn't work: The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I think T would need to be a generic argument in order for default() to work.

Comment: @mitch `default` takes a type parameter

Comment: +1... This _will_ work, but you also need to change the function signature.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `dynamic` here:

```
private static T Zero<T>()
{
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: Guffa had it right first... not sure why he deleted his answer.